# Where to ask question about querying two servers/services and only consuming fastest response?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have this question:

> In what conditions (if any) is it good practice to query two
>   servers/services and only consume the fastest response?
>
> I've asked what is now a deleted-by-Community question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) on
>   why would someone use javascript's `Promise.race`, and a high rep user
>   commented this:
>
> > If you have two services that compute some value you can query them both in parallel and use which ever value is returned first, rather
> >     than querying one, waiting for a failure, and then querying the
> >     second.
>
> I've googled about redundancy and this use case in general but I
>   couldn't find anything and, from my POV, it's never a good idea to
>   just add workload to a server/service if you're not going to use the
>   response.

I'm torn between these sites:

- [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)
- [superuser](https://superuser.com/)
- [ProWebmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)
- [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)
- Maybe even [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Sound more like an whiteboard question. Those might fit on Software Engineering.se. It might also be a topic for high reliability / fault tolerant systems. The theoretical aspects maybe fit on Computer Science.se. But I'm not a regular on any of those sites so check their help / meta or chat first before posting.

Comment: @rene I should've added a none-of-the-above option :) didn't even considered SWE. Good idea

Comment: Definitely **not** [webapps.se].

Comment: Question is entirely out of scope at Superuser.  It is seeking an opinion on how to program something.  It also would be out of scope at Serverfault.  It is helpful to read the help center, of a SE community, before submitting a question there.